# using strtok in C to assign value to a structure

Tags: c, strtok

i am receiving a default char array (first/last) in guest_init (and i need to initialize the values such that guest have default values ) is my following code correct? as when i run this g->first_name is always being assigned garbage. need some help.

```
struct guest {
    char last_name[30];
    char first_name[30];
};
struct auditorium_seating {
    struct guest **seating;
};
void guest_init_default(struct guest *g)
{

    *g->first_name = "???";
    *g->last_name = "???";
}
void guest_init(struct guest *g, char *info)
{
        strcpy(g->first_name, strtok(info, "/"));
        strcpy(g->last_name, strtok(NULL, "\0"));




}
void auditorium_seating_init(int rowNum, int columnNum, struct auditorium_seating *a)
{
    a->seating=malloc((sizeof(a->seating[rowNum][columnNum])));
    char string_arr[30]="aaa/bbb";
    for (int i = 0; i<rowNum; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j<columnNum; j++)
        {



            //guest_init_default(a->seating);
            guest_init(a->seating,string_arr);


        }
    }

}
```

auditorium_seating_init being called from main.

```
void main() {
    struct auditorium_seating auditorium_seating;
    struct guest temp_guest;
    int row, col, rowNum, columnNum;
    char guest_info[30];

    printf("Please enter a number of rows for an auditorium seating.");
    scanf_s("%d", &rowNum);

    printf("Please enter a number of columns for an auditorium seating.");
    scanf_s("%d", &columnNum);

    auditorium_seating_init(rowNum, columnNum, &auditorium_seating);

    printf("Please enter a guest information or enter \"Q\" to quit.");
}
```

Comment: For start, enable warnings and follow errors.

Comment: `strcpy(g->first_name, strtok(info, "/")); strcpy(g->last_name, strtok(NULL, "/"));`

Comment: yeah i did, but there were no errors.

Comment: And what about warnings? I'm sure there were. Follow comment from @BLUEPIXY

Comment: using @BLUEPIXY comment i get this (Unhandled exception at 0x0F86E033 (ucrtbased.dll) in Project2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
)

Comment: @AbdulKhan show how you call `guest_init`, the origin of the problem may be there. Best post a [MCVE].

Comment: @BLUEPIXY's solution is fine. What are you passing to your `guest_init()` function, a null pointer?

Comment: The pointer `g` does not seem to point to the correct object.

Comment: ok i edited with rest of the code

Comment: `guest_init(a->seating,string_arr);` --> `guest_init(&a->seating[rowNum][columnNum], string_arr);` : `string_arr` is already divided at the time of the second call.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY this is what i am trying to do (It instantiates a two-dimensional array of the size
"rowNum" by "columnNum" specified by the
parameters inside the struct a. Then it initializes each
guest element of this array using the guest_init
function. So, each guest will have default values for its
instance variables.) in the auditorium_seating_init function

Comment: [sample code](https://ideone.com/90e1CY)

Comment: i need a single 2d array instantiated for rowNum and columnNum, you have done 2 seperatley for rowNum and columnNum

Comment: _single 2d array_ What do you mean? If my understanding is correct, then `**` (`struct guest **seating;`) should not be used in that case.

Answer (score 3):

Enable your compiler warnings: `*g->first_name = "???";` is wrong.

And `strtok(NULL, "\0"));` is wrong too.

You probably want this:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct guest {
  char last_name[30];
  char first_name[30];
};

void guest_init(struct guest *g, char *info)
{
  strcpy(g->first_name, strtok(info, "/"));
  strcpy(g->last_name, strtok(NULL, "/"));
}

int main()
{
  struct guest g;
  char info[] = "Foo/Bar";
  guest_init(&g, info);
  printf("Last Name = %s\n", g.last_name);
  printf("First Name = %s\n", g.first_name);
}
```

There may be more errors related to `struct auditorium_seating *a`, but you didn't post that code.

Comment: sorry about that but i have added the rest now

Comment: @AbdulKhan: This answer solves your problem and you should be able to fix the rest of your code too. Your question is about very basic stuff of the C language: pointers, C-strings, dynamic memory allocation etc. Further the problems you have can all be found on with google and on StackOverflow already answered. You should take a [good C book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and learn the basics.

Comment: @AbdulKhan there are other problems in your code, show how you call `auditorium_seating_init` including the declarations of the variables involved.

Answer (score -2):

No, you must copy data to your structure, as you allocated memory inside it.

Read compiler errors and use it to fix your program.

Comment: Post it as comment instead.

Comment: Why? This answer definitive answers on question.